# Adding a execution line in flatmap causes the sequence to fail compilation

Tags: swift, rx-swift

When I add an execution line in the flatmap function, it causes the whole 
sequence to fail compilation.

The error is:

```
error: generic parameter 'O' could not be inferred
  }.addDisposableTo(DisposeBag())
```

Example:

```
private func askPayment(question: String) -> Observable<Void> { return Observable.just() }
private func askQuestion(question:String) -> Observable<Int> {return Observable.just(9) }

askPayment("xxx")
  .flatMapLatest { _ in return
    Observable.just()
  }.flatMapLatest { _ in
    // the offending line
    print ("this causes an error")
    return askQuestion("xxx")
  }.subscribeNext{ q in
    print ("subscribed")
  }.addDisposableTo(DisposeBag())
```

It does not appear to matter even when i add more type declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the line:

```
}.flatMapLatest { _ in
```

to:

```
}.flatMapLatest { _ -> Observable<Int> in
```

fixes it for me. Is that what you meant when you said you tried to "add more type declaration" and it didn't work?